# jQuery .append doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I want to insert something into my form, which is somewhere hard coded into plugin and I didn't want to mess with the plugin files, so I've found `.append`

```
<script>jQuery('#edit-profile').append('<p>smth</p>');</script>
```

I've written something like this and as far as I can see it should work. Console in Chrome doesn't shows me any bugs. Is here something wrong?

I'm using the newest jQuery and using jQuery instead of $ due to the wordpress safemode.

Comment: Add some relevant HTML

Comment: When things like this fail I tend to do a $('#edit-profile').length and make sure jquery can find the element in question

Comment: You'll need to read this: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap it in dom ready.Because `#edit-profile` should be there at the time of executing the script,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#edit-profile').append('<p>smth</p>');
});
```

Comment: This should work assuming `#edit-profile` actually exists and the content from the plugin is not loaded by ajax. If it is, they'll need to dig into the plugins API for some type of hook.

Answer (score 5):

You need the document ready handler -

```
<script>
jQuery(function() { // the document ready handler shorthand
    jQuery('#edit-profile').append('<p>smth</p>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried that before posting and didn't work - tried the answer from below and worked, thanks for your help anyway! :)